# volatile struct = struct not possible, why?

Tags: c++, struct, volatile

```
struct FOO{
    int a;
    int b;
    int c;
};

volatile struct FOO foo;

int main(void)
{
    foo.a = 10;
    foo.b = 10;
    foo.c = 10;
    struct FOO test = foo;

    return 0;
}
```

This won't compile, because 
`struct FOO test = foo;`
generates an error:

> error: binding reference of type 'const FOO&' to 'volatile FOO'
>   discards qualifiers

How can I copy a `volatile struct` into another `struct` in C++ (before C++11)?

Many people suggested to just delelte volatile, but I can't do that in that case, because I want to copy the current SPI-Reg setttings inside a µC and this is declared volatile by the manufacturer headers. 
I want to copy those settings, because the manufactuerer also provides an Library to use the SPI for EnDat-Communication, and I don't have access to the source-code. Since I have to change the SPI-Reg-Settings during runtime I want to easyly get back to the library SPI-settings without calling the init_endat()-lib fkt again (it's unspecified what happens if i call it twice).

Could I possibly use memcopy() for that?

As suggested, this is a copy of the following question.

[Why am I not provided with a default copy constructor from a volatile?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17217300/why-am-i-not-provided-with-a-default-copy-constructor-from-a-volatile)

Comment: Perhaps the first question is what do you want volatile for?   (hint: you probably don't)

Comment: The odds are approximately 100% that using `volatile` is a mistake. Are you dealing with memory mapped hardware? I didn't think so. Remove `volatile` from your vocabulary.

Comment: @JiveDadson There are many other valid uses of volatile (performance testing, mathematical computations, signal handlers just to name a few). I'm not arguing that the OP does one of these - just against the idea that volatile has no use outside low-level operations with hardware.

Comment: Which compiler gives you this error ?  Also, using "volatile" is useful when clearing memory that contains some sensitive data (e.g. encryption keys) even if no code reads this memory after clearing.  See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49084430/using-volatile-twice-in-an-r-value.

Comment: I think memcpy will suffer from the same error. Perhaps copying it memberwise is the only option.

Comment: Possible duplicate (sort of) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17217300/why-am-i-not-provided-with-a-default-copy-constructor-from-a-volatile

Comment: @n.m. I tried it, and if u typecast the Adress of the volatile instance to (const void*) it works. (if it is a good sulotion is another question)

memcpy(&struct_to_copy_to, (const void*)&struct_that_is_volatile, sizeof(struct_that_is_volatile));

Comment: @makum it will of course compile with a cast, but also a normal copy ctor will compile with a cast. Strictly speaking though it's UB.

Comment: I literally came here trying to find an answer to a similar question, working on embedded development, using volatile to interact with memory mapped hardware.  And the first thing I see is @JiveDadson being a condescending prick telling the OP he's clearly wrong for using volatile. This site is a cesspool.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

This is ill-formed because `FOO` has an implicit copy constructor defined as:

```
FOO(FOO const&);
```

And you write `FOO test = foo;` with `foo` of type `volatile FOO`, invoking:

```
FOO(volatile FOO const&);
```

But references-to-volatile to references-to-non-volatile implicit conversion is ill-formed.

From here, *two* solutions emerge:

1. don't make volatile to non-volatile conversions;
2. define a suited copy constructor or copy the object members "manually";
3. `const_cast` can remove the volatile qualifier, but this is undefined behavior to use that if your underlying object is effectively volatile.

> Could I possibly use memcopy() for that?

No you cannot, `memcpy` is incompatible with volatile objects: thre is no overload of it which takes pointers-to-volatile, and there is nothing you can do without invoking undefined behavior.

So, as a conclusion, your best shot if you cannot add a constructor to `FOO` is to define:

```
FOO FOO_copy(FOO volatile const& other)
{
    FOO result;
    result.a = other.a;
    result.b = other.b;
    result.c = other.c;
    return result;
}
```

Or with C++11's [`std::tie`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/tuple/tie):

```
FOO FOO_copy(FOO volatile const& other)
{
    FOO result;
    std::tie(result.a, result.b, result.c) = std::tie(other.a, other.b, other.c);
    return result;
}
```

Comment: You omitted the only correct answer:  0. Remove `volatile`.

Comment: @JiveDadson it's kinda included in 1. ;) though, `volatile` might be really needed in OP's context, we don't know. But we know from [OP's profile page](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9262651/makum) they are an _embedded_ software engineer, so...

Comment: I guess it's possible. I had a use for volatile about 23 years ago. It can happen.

Comment: You say "two solutions", then provide a list of three items.  I think the list item shouldn't be part of the list (since it's not a solution).

Comment: @TobySpeight that's the joke. Its funny because the list does actually contain exactly two solutions, is it not?

Comment: It seems to me like the issue here is that the C++ implicit copy constructor uses a reference to the source value, right? There is no fundamental reason why it could not instead read the value of the source struct and then use that as a value and write that value to the destination struct without violating the semantics of the volatile, right?

Comment: It looks like the correct answer is "you cannot do this because of the way the standard choose to implement the copy constructor"....
https://stackoverflow.com/a/17218983/3152071

Answer (score 21):

To give another approach to an answer, to address why this doesn't make sense, rather than just where the C++ standard says this is invalid:

The whole point of `volatile` is that you have precise control over which variable gets accessed when. That means given `volatile int i, j;`, `i = 1; j = 2;` and `j = 2; i = 1;` do not do the same thing. The compiler cannot freely transform one into the other. The same applies to reads: given `volatile int i, j; int x, y;`, `x = i; y = j;` and `y = j; x = i;` do not do the same thing. The presence of `volatile` means the accesses *must* happen in *exactly* the order you specified.

Now, in your example, what should `struct FOO test = foo;` do? You've never specified whether you want to first read `foo.a`, then `foo.b`, finally `foo.c`, or perhaps first read `foo.c`, then `foo.b`, finally `foo.a`, or perhaps some other order.

You can, if you wish, do this:

```
struct FOO test;
test.a = foo.a;
test.b = foo.b;
test.c = foo.c;
```

Here, you explicitly specify the order of the accesses to `foo`'s fields, so you avoid the problem.

Comment: I like this approach.

Comment: That's not what `volatile` means.  That's what std::atomic with memory order  std::memory_order_seq_cst means.  Visual C++ makes some memory order guarantees for volatile unless you set a standard-compliance flag, but the promises are not that strong. `volatile` is for accessing memory-mapped hardware only and I guess UNIX signal handlers.

Comment: @JiveDadson You're reading more into my answer than what I actually wrote. What I wrote *is* exactly what `volatile` means. Per [intro.execution]p8.1: "Access to volatile objects are evaluated strictly according to the rules of the abstract machine."

Comment: @hvd `volatile` guarantees individual accesses will not be optimized away, but does not prevent them from being reordered with others (that is, `volatile` in C++ does not establish happens-before order).

Comment: I like how `volatile` is sooo mystical for some developers :) @JAB you know how the compiler is allowed to reorder instruction following the "as-if" rule? Well this rule does not apply for volatile objects (see `[intro.execution]/8.1` quoted above). What you are talking about is related to multi-threaded programs, and yes in this context `volatile` does not help. hvd's answer is about in-thread instruction order.

Comment: @YSC It's been a while since I delved into the nitty-gritty bits so I'll yield to you on that.

Comment: @JAB volatile is rarely useful and is misused too often, when in doubt, it's better not to use it than have a false sense of security, in that you're right.

Comment: I can do ` typedef long long twolongs; volatile twolongs x = 1; volatile twolongs y = x;` on a 32-bit machine no problem, even though that assignment necessarily is equivalent to  if `twolongs` were defined with `struct twlongs {long a; long b};` so this is not about needing to specifically sequence assignments of internal non-atomic data. This is about the way the struct copy constructor is defined. They *could* have done it a way that was compatible with volatile semantics.

Answer (score 2):

You haven't provided enough details about your problem to give a more precise assessment, but the solution to whatever problem you're trying to solve is almost certainly not to use `volatile`. "Volatile" means that the value can change from under your feet: the two typical good use cases are variables changed from within UNIX signal handlers and memory-mapped registers. Volatile is not enough for variables shared among threads, notably.

The reason you are getting this error is that your compiler is trying to find a `FOO(volatile FOO&)` copy constructor, which is never automatically generated.

Comment: The other use case of `volatile` is for variables that are used in the presence of `setjmp` and `longjmp`.  Which I would caution against using without a very, very good reason.