# Could this publish / check-for-update class for a single writer + reader use memory_order_relaxed or acquire/release for efficiency?

Tags: c++, atomic, lock-free, memory-barriers, stdatomic

## Introduction

I have a small class which make use of std::atomic for a lock free operation. Since this class is being called massively, it's affecting the performance and I'm having trouble.

## Class description

The class similar to a LIFO, but once the pop() function is called, it only return the last written element of its ring-buffer (only if there are new elements since last pop()).

A single thread is calling push(), and another single thread is calling pop().

## Source I've read

Since this is using too much time of my computer time, I decided to study a bit further the std::atomic class and its memory_order. I've read a lot of memory_order post avaliable in StackOverflow and other sources and books, but I'm not able to get a clear idea about the different modes. Specially, I'm struggling between acquire and release modes: I fail too see why they are different to memory_order_seq_cst.

## What I **think** each memory order do using my words, from my own research

**memory_order_relaxed:** In the same thread, the atomic operations are instant, but other threads may fail to see the lastest values instantly, they will need some time until they are updated. The code can be re-ordered freely by the compiler or OS.

**memory_order_acquire / release:** Used by atomic::load. It prevents the lines of code there are before this from being reordered (the compiler/OS may reorder after this line all it want), and reads the lastest value that was stored on this atomic using **memory_order_release** or **memory_order_seq_cst** in this thread or another thread. **memory_order_release** also prevents that code after it may be reordered. So, in an acquire/release, all the code between both can be shuffled by the OS. I'm not sure if that's between same thread, or different threads.

**memory_order_seq_cst:** Easiest to use because it's like the natural writting we are used with variables, instantly refreshing the values of other threads load functions.

## The LockFreeEx class

```cpp
template<typename T>
class LockFreeEx
{
public:
    void push(const T& element)
    {
        const int wPos = m_position.load(std::memory_order_seq_cst);
        const int nextPos = getNextPos(wPos);
        m_buffer[nextPos] = element;
        m_position.store(nextPos, std::memory_order_seq_cst);
    }

    const bool pop(T& returnedElement)
    {

        const int wPos = m_position.exchange(-1, std::memory_order_seq_cst);
        if (wPos != -1)
        {
            returnedElement = m_buffer[wPos]; 
            return true;
        }
        else
        {
            return false;
        }
    }

private:
    static constexpr int maxElements = 8;
    static constexpr int getNextPos(int pos) noexcept {return (++pos == maxElements)? 0 : pos;}
    std::array<T, maxElements> m_buffer;
    std::atomic<int> m_position {-1};
};
```

## How I expect it could be improved

So, my first idea was using memory_order_relaxed in all atomic operations, since the pop() thread is in a loop looking for avaliable updates in pop function each 10-15 ms, then it's allowed to fail in the firsts pop() functions to realize later that there is a new update. It's only a bunch of milliseconds.

Another option would be using release/acquire - but I'm not sure about them. Using release in **all** store() and acquire in **all** load() functions.

Unfortunately, *all the memory_order I described seems to work*, and I'm not sure when will they fail, if they are supposed to fail.

## Final

Please, could you tell me if you see some problem using relaxed memory order here? Or should I use release/acquire (maybe a further explanation on these could help me)? why?

I think that *relaxed* is the best for this class, in all its store() or load(). But I'm not sure!

Thanks for reading.

## EDIT: EXTRA EXPLANATION:

Since I see everyone is asking for the 'char', I've changed it to int, problem solved! But it doesn't it the one I want to solve.

The class, as I stated before, is something likely to a LIFO but where only matters the last element pushed, if there is any.

I have a big struct T (copiable and asignable), that I must share between two threads in a lock-free way. So, the only way I know to do it is using a circular buffer that writes the last known value for T, and a atomic which know the index of the last value written. When there isn't any, the index would be -1.

Notice that my push thread must know when there is a "new T" avaliable, that's why pop() returns a bool.

Thanks again to everyone trying to assist me with memory orders! :)

## AFTER READING SOLUTIONS:

```
template<typename T>
class LockFreeEx
{
public:
    LockFreeEx() {}
    LockFreeEx(const T& initValue): m_data(initValue) {}

    // WRITE THREAD - CAN BE SLOW, WILL BE CALLED EACH 500-800ms
    void publish(const T& element)
    {
        // I used acquire instead relaxed to makesure wPos is always the lastest w_writePos value, and nextPos calculates the right one
        const int wPos = m_writePos.load(std::memory_order_acquire);
        const int nextPos = (wPos + 1) % bufferMaxSize;
        m_buffer[nextPos] = element;
        m_writePos.store(nextPos, std::memory_order_release);
    }


    // READ THREAD - NEED TO BE VERY FAST - CALLED ONCE AT THE BEGGINING OF THE LOOP each 2ms
    inline void update() 
    {
        // should I change to relaxed? It doesn't matter I don't get the new value or the old one, since I will call this function again very soon, and again, and again...
        const int writeIndex = m_writePos.load(std::memory_order_acquire); 
        // Updating only in case there is something new... T may be a heavy struct
        if (m_readPos != writeIndex)
        {
            m_readPos = writeIndex;
            m_data = m_buffer[m_readPos];
        }
    }
    // NEED TO BE LIGHTNING FAST, CALLED MULTIPLE TIMES IN THE READ THREAD
    inline const T& get() const noexcept {return m_data;}

private:
    // Buffer
    static constexpr int bufferMaxSize = 4;
    std::array<T, bufferMaxSize> m_buffer;

    std::atomic<int> m_writePos {0};
    int m_readPos = 0;

    // Data
    T m_data;
};
```

Comment: 1) You should use exactly the necessary ordering for your algorithm. 2) Some CPU are strongly ordered and always provide release in store operations, when done in asm. 3) Just because the CPU provides a semantic doesn't imply the compiler will, you still need to say release when you mean release.

Comment: `char` is not a proper numeric type; it's a monobyte character storage type and a raw memory access type.

Comment: I figured there is exactly one writing thread and one reading thread. How do you prevent overflow?

Comment: Notice I'm using a char, but it could be an int too. A char is enough because the getNextPosition() function doesn't allow that char exceed the value '8' (maxElements), preventing overflow.

Comment: Do you use a smaller type as an optimization?

Comment: Yes, but that was before I knew that using smaller types doesn't improve performance.

Comment: `char` might be either signed or unsigned if you don't explicitly specify it. It actually doesn't matter in your code, but it is something to keep in mind.

Comment: This is not a common LIFO. As I stated in "Class description", it only must return the most recent added value if any. The others aren't important and should be ignored. So if one thread pushes twice, and later a pop is called by the other thread, if will return the last T value by argument. If push hasn't been called, it will return false. T is a big variable that doesn't meet the Atomic lock-free requisistes. So my idea to overcome this was the circular buffer and returning the last value if any, to avoid data race.

Comment: @JuanJuezSarmiento: you might just want a SeqLock instead.  It's hard to avoid C++ UB while getting a C++ compiler to generate safe machine code for any particular target, but fortunately this is one of the rare cases where "what the compiler doesn't know can't hurt it" because data-race UB isn't visible at compile time.  See [Implementing 64 bit atomic counter with 32 bit atomics](//stackoverflow.com/q/54611003) and maybe also [Optimal way to pass a few variables between 2 threads pinning different CPUs](//stackoverflow.com/q/53906576)

Comment: @Peter Cordes, thanks for your input, it seems really complicated the use of a SeqLock (and believe in one that doesn't fail, I cannot find a guaranteed implementation), but I will continue trying to understand. This 'simple' problem is really hard!

Comment: What you've invented is like RCU but without the safety.  [Like in RCU](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Read-copy-update), the read side is wait-free (never has to retry) and could be read-only if you weren't marking it as "done".  But if the read side sleeps for some reasons, the array entry it's using could be overwritten before the reader is finished reading it, leading to tearing.  If you know that the chance of that happening is small enough (and the resulting error isn't catastrophic), given the known write speeds and other details of your use-case, then yeah this might be a good design.

Comment: @Peter Cordes, it's very helpful. I for sure know that the read side cannot wait for nothing and cannot be stopped (it's audio) and it's poped each 5-10ms, and the write side is the user input, which is more slower, a faster one could do a push once each 500ms. I'm currently profiling with the design that ixSci gave me - I'll tell you know the result. Do you find his memory order setup right?

Comment: I'd include comments in the code to describe the fact that this is safe for a single writer, multiple readers.  Also, I might include a `claimed` flag in each array element.  In your current design, readers and the writer all contend for access to the cache line containing `m_position`.  Oh, and **if a reader "claims" element 0, the next write will be to that same element, potentially mid-read!!**

Comment: Why is `m_data` even part of this class?  Seems like that "cache" should be separate.  You want it not to be in the same cache line as `m_writePos` so it can stay hot in the reader core's L1d cache, not getting invalidated by false-sharing.  At least put `m_writePos` (and maybe also `m_readPos`) *before* the array, farther from `m_data` so they're not in the same cache line.  I pointed out the false-sharing problem in my answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your writer only needs `release`, not seq-cst, but `relaxed` is too weak.  You can't publish a value for `m_position` until *after* the non-atomic assignment to the corresponding `m_buffer[]` entry.  **You need release ordering to make sure the `m_position` store is visible to other threads only *after* all earlier memory operations. (Including the non-atomic assignment).  https://preshing.com/20120913/acquire-and-release-semantics/**

This has to "synchronize-with" an acquire or seq_cst load in the reader.  Or at least `mo_consume` in the reader.

In theory you also need `wpos = m_position` to be at least `acquire` (or `consume` in the reader), not relaxed, because C++11's memory model is weak enough for things like value-prediction which can let the compiler speculatively use a value for `wPos` before the load actually takes a value from coherent cache.

(In practice on real CPUs, a crazy compiler could do this with test/branch to introduce a control dependency, allowing branch prediction + speculative execution to break the data dependency for a likely value of `wPos`.)

But with normal compilers don't do that.  On CPUs other than DEC Alpha, the data dependency in the source code of `wPos = m_position` and then using `m_buffer[wPos]` will create a data dependency in the asm, like `mo_consume` is supposed to take advantage of.  Real ISAs other than Alpha guarantee dependency-ordering for dependent loads.  (And even on Alpha, using a relaxed atomic exchange might be enough to close the tiny window that exists on the few real Alpha CPUs that allow this reordering.)

When compiling for x86, there's no downside at all to using `mo_acquire`; it doesn't cost any extra barriers.  There can be on other ISAs, like 32-bit ARM where `acquire` costs a barrier, so "cheating" with a relaxed load could be a win that's still safe in practice.  Current compilers always strengthen `mo_consume` to `mo_acquire` so we unfortunately can't take advantage of it.

---

**You already have a real-word race condition even using `seq_cst`.**

- initial state: `m_position = 0`
- reader "claims" slot 0 by exchanging in a `m_position = -1` and reads *part of* `m_buffer[0];`
- reader sleeps for some reason (e.g. timer interrupt deschedules it), or simply races with a writer.
- writer reads `wPos = m_position` as `-1`, and calculates `nextPos = 0`.
  **It overwrites the partially-read `m_buffer[0]`**
- reader wakes up and finishes reading, getting a torn `T &element`.  Data race UB in the C++ abstract machine, and tearing in practice.

Adding a 2nd check of `m_position` after the read (like a SeqLock) can't detect this in every case because the writer doesn't update `m_position` until *after* writing the buffer element.

Even though you your real use-case has long gaps between reads and writes, this defect can bite you with just one read and write happening at almost the same time.

> I for sure know that the read side cannot wait for nothing and cannot be stopped (it's audio) and it's poped each 5-10ms, and the write side is the user input, which is more slower, a faster one could do a push once each 500ms.

A millisecond is *ages* on a modern CPU.  Inter-thread latency is often something like 60 ns, so fractions of a microsecond, e.g. from a quad-core Intel x86.  As long as you don't sleep on a mutex, it's not a problem to spin-retry once or twice before giving up.

---

Code review:

> The class similar to a LIFO, but once the pop() function is called, it only return the last written element of its ring-buffer (only if there are new elements since last pop()).

This isn't a real queue or stack: push and pop aren't great names.  "publish" and "read" or "get" might be better and make it more obvious what this is for.

I'd include comments in the code to describe the fact that this is safe for a single writer, multiple readers.  (The non-atomic increment of `m_position` in `push` makes it clearly unsafe for multiple writers.)

Even so, it's kinda weird even with 1 writer + 1 reader running at the same time.  If a read starts while a write is in progress, it will get the "old" value instead of spin-waiting for a fraction of a microsecond to get the new value.  Then next time it reads there will already be a new value waiting; the one it just missed seeing last time.  So e.g. `m_position` can update in this order: 2, -1, 3.

That might or might not be desirable, depending on whether "stale" data has any value, and on acceptability of the reader blocking if the writer sleeps mid-write.  Or even without the writer sleeping, of spin-waiting.

The standard pattern for rarely written smallish data with *multiple* read-only readers is a SeqLock.  e.g. for publishing a 128-bit current timestamp on a CPU that can't atomically read or write a 128-bit value.  See [Implementing 64 bit atomic counter with 32 bit atomics](https://stackoverflow.com/q/54611003)

---

### Possible design changes

To make this safe, we could let the writer run free, always wrapping around its circular buffer, and **have the reader keep track of the last element it looked at.**

If there's only one reader, this should be a simple non-atomic variable.  If it's an instance variable, at least put it on the other side of `m_buffer[]` from the write-position.

```
    // Possible failure mode: writer wraps around between reads, leaving same m_position
    // single-reader
    const bool read(T &elem)
    {
        // FIXME: big hack to get this in a separate cache line from the instance vars
        // maybe instead use alignas(64) int m_lastread as a class member, and/or on the other side of m_buffer from m_position.
        static int lastread = -1;

        int wPos = m_position.load(std::memory_order_acquire);    // or cheat with relaxed to get asm that's like "consume"
        if (lastread == wPos)
            return false;

        elem = m_buffer[wPos];
        lastread = wPos;
        return true;
    }
```

You want `lastread` in a separate cache line from the stuff the writer writes.  Otherwise the reader's updates of readPos will be slower because of false-sharing with the writer's writes and vice versa.

This lets the reader(s) be truly read-only wrt. the cache lines written by the writer.  It will still take MESI traffic to request read access to lines that are in Modified state after the writer writes them, though.  But the writer can still *read* `m_position` with no cache miss, so it can get its stores into the store buffer right away.  It only has to wait for an RFO to get exclusive ownership of the cache line(s) before it can commit the element and the updated `m_position` from its store buffer to L1d cache.

**TODO: let `m_position` increment without manual wrapping**, so we have a write sequence number that takes a very long time to wrap around, avoiding false-negative early out from `lastread == wPos`.

Use `wPos & (maxElements-1)` as the index.  And `static_assert(maxElements & (maxElements-1) == 0, "maxElements must be a power of 2");`

Then the only danger is undetected tearing in a tiny time-window if the writer has wrapped all the way around and is writing the element being read.  For frequent reads and infrequent writes, and a buffer that's not too small, this should never happen.  Checking the `m_position` again after a read (like a SeqLock, similar to below) narrows the race window to only writes that are still in progress.

---

**If there are multiple readers, another good option might be a `claimed` flag in each `m_buffer` entry**.  So you'd define

```
template<typename T>
class WaitFreePublish
{

private:
    struct {
        alignas(32) T elem;           // at most 2 elements per cache line
        std::atomic<int8_t> claimed;  // writers sets this to 0, readers try to CAS it to 1
                                      // could be bool if we don't end up needing 3 states for anything.
                                      // set to "1" in the constructor?  or invert and call it "unclaimed"
    } m_buffer[maxElements];

    std::atomic<int> m_position {-1};
}
```

If `T` has padding at the end, it's a shame we can't take advantage of that for the `claimed` flag :/

This avoids the possible failure mode of comparing positions: if the writer wraps around between reads, the worst we get is tearing.  And we could detect such tearing by having the writer clear the `claimed` flag first, before writing the rest of the element.

With no other threads writing `m_position`, we can definitely use a relaxed load without worry.  We could even cache the write-position somewhere else, but the reader hopefully isn't invalidating the cache-line containing `m_position` very often.  And apparently in your use-case, writer performance/latency probably isn't a big deal.

So the writer + reader could look like this, with SeqLock-style tearing detection using the known update-order for claimed flag, element, and m_position.

```
/// claimed flag per array element supports concurrent readers

    // thread-safety: single-writer only
    // update claimed flag first, then element, then m_position.
    void publish(const T& elem)
    {
        const int wPos = m_position.load(std::memory_order_relaxed);
        const int nextPos = getNextPos(wPos);

        m_buffer[nextPos].claimed.store(0, std::memory_order_relaxed);
        std::atomic_thread_fence(std::memory_order_release);  // make sure that `0` is visible *before* the non-atomic element modification
        m_buffer[nextPos].elem = elem;

        m_position.store(nextPos, std::memory_order_release);
    }

    // thread-safety: multiple readers are ok.  First one to claim an entry gets it
    // check claimed flag before/after to detect overwrite, like a SeqLock
    const bool read(T &elem)
    {
        int rPos = m_position.load(std::memory_order_acquire);

        int8_t claimed = m_buffer[rPos].claimed.load(std::memory_order_relaxed);
        if (claimed != 0)
            return false;      // read-only early-out

        claimed = 0;
        if (!m_buffer[rPos].claimed.compare_exchange_strong(
                claimed, 1, std::memory_order_acquire, std::memory_order_relaxed))
            return false;  // strong CAS failed: another thread claimed it

        elem = m_buffer[rPos].elem;

        // final check that the writer didn't step on this buffer during read, like a SeqLock
        std::atomic_thread_fence(std::memory_order_acquire);    // LoadLoad barrier

        // We expect it to still be claimed=1 like we set with CAS
        // Otherwise we raced with a writer and elem may be torn.
        //  optionally retry once or twice in this case because we know there's a new value waiting to be read.
        return m_buffer[rPos].claimed.load(std::memory_order_relaxed) == 1;

        // Note that elem can be updated even if we return false, if there was tearing.  Use a temporary if that's not ok.
    }
```

Using `claimed = m_buffer[rPos].exchange(1)` and checking for `claimed==0` would be another option, vs. CAS-strong.  Maybe slightly more efficient on x86.  On LL/SC machines I guess CAS might be able to bail out without doing a write at all if it finds a mismatch with `expected`, in which case the read-only check is pointless.

**I used `.claimed.compare_exchange_strong(claimed, 1)` with success ordering = `acquire` to make sure that read of `claimed` happens-before reading `.elem`.**

The "failure" memory ordering can be `relaxed`:  If we see it already claimed by another thread, we give up and don't look at any shared data.

The memory-ordering of the store part of `compare_exchange_strong` can be `relaxed`, so we just need `mo_acquire`, not `acq_rel`.  Readers don't do any *other* stores to the shared data, and I don't think the ordering of the store matters wrt. to the loads.  CAS is an atomic RMW.  Only one thread's CAS can succeed on a given buffer element because they're all trying to set it from 0 to 1.  That's how atomic RMWs work, regardless of being relaxed or seq_cst or anything in between.

It doesn't need to be seq_cst: we *don't* need to flush the store buffer or whatever to make sure the store is visible before this thread reads `.elem`.  Just being an atomic RMW is enough to stop multiple threads from actually thinking they succeed.  Release would just make sure it can't move earlier, ahead of the relaxed read-only check.  That wouldn't be a correctness problem.  Hopefully no x86 compilers would do that at compile time.  (At runtime on x86, RMW atomic operations are always seq_cst.)

I think being an RMW makes it impossible for it to "step on" a write from a writer (after wrapping around).  But this might be real-CPU implementation detail, not ISO C++.  In the global modification order for any given `.claimed`, I think the RMW stays together, and the "acquire" ordering does keep it ahead of the read of the `.elem`.  A `release` store that wasn't part of a RMW would be a potential problem though: a writer could wrap around and put `claimed=0` in a new entry, then the reader's store could eventually commit and set it to 1, when actually no reader has ever read that element.

---

**If we're very sure the reader doesn't need to detect writer wrap-around of the circular buffer, leave out the `std::atomic_thread_fence` in the writer and reader**.  (The claimed and the non-atomic element store will still be ordered by the release-store to `m_position`).  The reader can be simplified to leave out the 2nd check and always return true if it gets past the CAS.

Notice that  `m_buffer[nextPos].claimed.store(0, std::memory_order_release);` would *not* be sufficient to stop later non-atomic stores from appearing before it: release-stores are a one-way barrier, unlike release fences.  A release-fence is like a 2-way StoreStore barrier.  (Free on x86, cheap on other ISAs.)

This SeqLock-style tearing detection doesn't technically avoid UB in the C++ abstract machine, unfortunately.  There's no good / safe way to express this pattern in ISO C++, and it's known to be safe in asm on real hardware.  Nothing actually uses the torn value (assuming `read()`'s caller ignores its `elem` value if it returns false).

Making `elem` a `std::atomic<T>` would be defeat the entire purpose: that would use a spinlock to get atomicity so it might as well use it directly.

Using `volatile T elem` would break `buffer[i].elem = elem` because unlike C, C++ doesn't allow copying a volatile struct to/from a regular struct.  ([volatile struct = struct not possible, why?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49367852/volatile-struct-struct-not-possible-why)).  This is highly annoying for a SeqLock type of pattern where you'd like the compiler to emit efficient code to copy the whole object representation, optionally using SIMD vectors.  You won't get that if you write a constructor or assignment operator that takes a `volatile &T` argument and does individual members.  So clearly `volatile` is the wrong tool, and that only leaves compiler memory barriers to make sure the non-atomic object is fully read or fully written before the barrier.  `std::atomic_thread_fence` is I *think* actually safe for that, like `asm("" ::: "memory")` in GNU C.  It works in practice on current compilers.

Comment: I cannot be grateful enough for your explanation. I've been absorbing it during hours and I've improved the class with the tips you show me here in your solution. I only have a quick doubt that I will do in the next comment about the ´relaxed´ memory order.

Comment: if I have a thread constantly each 2 ms doing atomic::load(mo_relaxed), what's the worst thing that may happen? Maybe that I do not use the lastest value stored and instead I'd be using an old one during some infinitesimal time? - I ask this because in my code, I', not interested in most recent stored value... while it arrives in some moment!

Comment: I've edited to update the class, I think it's more solid now

Comment: I suppose cheating with `mo_relaxed` to get `mo_consume` ordering is a good idea if you know what you're doing.  Perhaps an `mo_acquire` compiler barrier could be helpful to prevent the crazy compiler behavior that you describe.

Comment: @LWimsey: I don't think `atomic_thread_fence(mo_acquire)` after a relaxed  load is ever going to be cheaper than `load(mo_acquire)`.  It's strictly stronger, and ISAs like AArch64 will probably end up with a stand-alone barrier instead of an `ldar`  (it has acquire / sequential-release load/store instructions in the ISA, unlike most which just have barriers).  `atomic_signal_fence(mo_acquire)` wouldn't prevent "crazy" optimizations like branching to break a data dependency because *from within the same thread* things appear ot have happened in program order.

Comment: I was referring to a compiler barrier; i.e. `atomic_signal_fence`. It does everything `atomic_thread_fence` does (compiler ordering), except the generation of asm barriers (e.g. no `lwsync` on PowerPC). I think that's what you need for your `relaxed` solution to 'emulate' `mo_consume`; you want to data-dependency-order the assembly without the `lwsync`.

Comment: @LWimsey: `atomic_signal_fence` will make sure the load appears first in program order, but *doesn't* force a data dependency.  It only has to make sure this thread sees stores done by a signal/interrupt handler that ran *in this thread* (aka on the same core), where hardware preserves the illusion of everything happening in program order.  Transforming to `if(pos == 0) special case with hardcoded zero` is still legal.  Remember we've told the compiler it's a `relaxed` load so it has no reason to avoid anything that allows that runtime reordering of the load to happen later.

Comment: The C++ standard says about `atomic_signal_fence`: "_... Compiler optimizations and reorderings of loads and stores are inhibited in the same way as with atomic_thread_fence, but the hardware fence instructions that atomic_thread_fence would have inserted are not emitted._"

Comment: @LWimsey: yes, exactly.  `atomic_thread_fence(mo_acquire)` doesn't force later operations to have a data dependency on earlier operations; an acquire barrier creates runtime ordering with an actual barrier instruction (and of course compile-time ordering around that barrier).  If you use the `signal_fence` version, you get no barrier and still no requirement for a dependency, *only* compile-time ordering of load operations.

Answer (score 5):

Memory order is not about when you see some particular change to an atomic object but rather about what this change can guarantee about the surrounding code. Relaxed atomics guarantee nothing except the change to the atomic object itself: the change will be atomic. But you can't use relaxed atomics in any synchronization context.

And you have some code which *requires* synchronization. You want to pop something that was pushed and not trying to pop what has not been pushed yet. So if you use a relaxed operation then there is no guarantee that your pop will see this push code:

```
m_buffer[nextPos] = element;
m_position.store(nextPos, std::memory_relaxed);
```

as it is written. It just as well can see it this way:

```
m_position.store(nextPos, std::memory_relaxed);
m_buffer[nextPos] = element;
```

So you might try to get an element from the buffer which is not there yet. Hence, you have to use some synchronization and at least use acquire/release memory order.

---

And to your actual code. I think the order can be as follows:

```
const char wPos = m_position.load(std::memory_order_relaxed);
...
m_position.store(nextPos, std::memory_order_release);
...
const char wPos = m_position.exchange(-1, memory_order_acquire);
```

Comment: Thank you for the clarification about the memory orders. Please could you suggest me how would you use the acquire/release in the push/pop function?

Comment: A publishing operation, when you make new data available, almost always needs to be a release. The only way to make use of a release operation is another thread is to check whether is happened and do an acquire.

Comment: @JuanJuezSarmiento that's a little bit tricky because I do not understand your code. I do not see why there is a buffer at all since you use only the latest element. If you remove all this position manipulation and just use one object instead of the buffer with atomic flag then you will need a release order on store (push) and acquire on pop.

Comment: I need to use a buffer because T is not atomic (it cannot be lock free, it's too big for that). So the only way to make sure that I'm not going to read an element that is being pushed currently is reading the prior element.

Comment: @JuanJuezSarmiento I have added the memory order which seems right to me. But note that I have no idea if your algorithm is right at all. It looks suspicious to me.

Comment: @JuanJuezSarmiento and ixSci:  I think in `push`, the `m_position.load` needs to be `acquire` to make sure it happens *before* you write anything to the array element. Actually even that's not safe: if a reader swapped a `-1` into `m_position` and then started reading the old `m_position = 0`, an acquire load still doesn't save you from a write starting *after* that and stepping on the non-atomic data while it's being read. So I think you want a `claimed` flag inside each array element and let the writer just loop over the circular buffer. Then reader just needs an acquire load of `m_position`

Comment: @PeterCordes good point about the claimed flag! Anyway, using a profiler I dont have almost any performance difference between using acquire/release flags or seq/cst for this case - only with relaxed flag which seems impossible for this case.

Comment: Instead a ClaimFlag, I would use another Atomic with the current read position - so i'd check if writePostion and readPosition are the before doing the read.

Comment: @PeterCordes please let me ask you something. Using the original ixSci solution, I thought the relaxed load in push function would be read before the release, but it also mean that it should be read before the OS uses that variable. I mean:The OS need to know the wPos before executing a line that is using the the wPos, right? I thought that would force an order!

Comment: Are you on x86?  acq/rel are free (only have to block compile-time reordering), but seq-cst stores cost extra.  Atomic RMW always strengthens to seq-cst on x86.  Anyway, I don't see why you'd want an atomic `readpos`, or how you'd safely check anything about two separate atomic variables.  Unless you put them in a struct of two 16-bit integers or something so you could do one atomic load and get them both.  At that point you're basically inventing a queue, and introducing even more possible contention between reader and writer instead of reducing it by moving the flag to the array element.

Comment: @JuanJuezSarmiento: You mean the CPU?  The OS doesn't look at individual machine-code instructions.  Anyway yes in practice on normal CPUs a data dependency will be sufficient.  That's not the case in the C++11 memory model, though: it's weak enough to allow things like value-prediction, and DEC Alpha's extremely weak memory ordering where even `mo_consume` needs a barrier.  But sure, if you want more performance on an ARM CPU or something then `relaxed` for that load is fine.  The compiler will be forced to make machine code with a data dependency on the load result from `m_position`.

Comment: I'm on x64. Yes, I know what you mean. Having a writepos and readpos wound mean a double read. Maybe I could do it with only `readpos` using negatives or offsets when the flag would be read, but that would mean that the exchange wouldn't be atomic. I must thing about this. After all sending an struct to another thread in a LockFree way should be possible with low CPU usage...

Comment: x86-64 is one version of x86, so yes, you're on x86.  It's annoying that Microsoft made up their own terminology where "x86" means "32-bit x86", instead of just "x86 in general, including 32 and 64-bit modes" like it means in most computer-architecture discussions.  "x86" is obviously the most convenient term for that vs. ARM vs. MIPS.

Comment: @PeterCordes no, it doesn't need acquire order. For the push thread it always happen before the writing to the buffer and for the pop thread there is no difference and no sync with this code happens anyway. Regarding _claimed_ flag: I agree. As I said, I do not think the algorithm in the question is right, I just provided the flags for the existing code.

Comment: Agreed.  `mo_acquire` would only shorten the potential race window, not close it.  (And only on C++ implementations where we don't get ordering for free because of the data dependency.  I think even DEC Alpha couldn't break this because it's a dependent store, not a dependent load.  But C++11 in the abstract does allow the reordering of the load with the non-atomic data store.  e.g. by value-prediction, or inventing a "switch"-like statement that breaks the data dependency with a branch, allowing branch-prediction + speculative execution.  i.e. only hypothetical systems.)